# web3 promise not resolving in clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript, web3js

I have the following cljs code where I want to deploy a contract:

```
  (go (let [web3
            (Web3. (.-givenProvider Web3))

            ego
            (-> (<p! (.. web3 -eth (getAccounts)))
                (nth 0))

            contract
            (new (.. web3 -eth -Contract)
              (.-abi (js/JSON.parse contract-json))
              nil
              (clj->js {:transactionConfirmationBlocks 3}))

            contract-deploy
            (.. contract
                (deploy (clj->js
                          {:arguments [ipfs]
                           :data (.-bytecode (js/JSON.parse contract-json))})))]
          ;;(prn "ego is " ego)
          (let [contract-send
                (.. contract-deploy
                    (send (clj->js {:from ego}) 
                          (fn [err tx-hash] 
                            (prn "err is " err
                                 "tx hash is " tx-hash))))
                 

                contract-instance
                (try
                  (<p!
                    (.. contract-send
                        (on "error" (fn [obj] (js/console.log "error " obj)))
                        (on "sending" (fn [obj] (prn "sending " obj)))
                        (on "receipt" (fn [receipt] 
                                       (prn "contract address is")
                                       (.-contractAddress receipt)))
                        (on "confirmation" (fn [confirmation-number receipt]
                                              (dispatch [:stop-loading])    
                                              (prn "confirmation number"
                                                   confirmation-number)
                                              (prn "receipt"
                                                   receipt)))))
                  (catch js/Object e
                    (.log js/console "contract error " e)))]
            (dispatch [:issue-nfts contract-instance
                       contract-json ego]))))
```

and for some reason, contract-instance isn't resolving, which means that the dispatch after it isn't being called. I don't know why it isn't resolving. It was working before and has suddenly stopped working. How to fix this? The contract is confirmed on metamask but the promise isn't resolving in web3. I'm using web3 version 1.5.2